# What happens to angle between vectors through base transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, angle, change-of-basis

I am currently working with vectors in $\mathbb{R}$^2. For my specific project,  it is beneficial to identify a non-standard basis as "new standard basis" of $\mathbb{R}$^2. For example, instead of working with basis $B$ (Euclidean coordinates)

$$B = \left\lbrace
\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 1\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ \sqrt{3}\end{pmatrix}
\right\rbrace,$$

I do my calculations with my "new standard basis" $B'$

$$B' = \left\lbrace
\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}
\right\rbrace.$$

Here, I identify $\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}$ with $\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ \sqrt{3}\end{pmatrix}$ with $\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}$. So, when working with $B'$, vector  $\begin{pmatrix}a \\ b\end{pmatrix}$ corresponds to $\begin{pmatrix}a + b\\ a+\sqrt{3}b\end{pmatrix}$ using $B$.

**Question:**
Working with $B'$, I calculate the angle between, e.g.,  $\begin{pmatrix}2 \\ 3\end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix}4 \\ 5\end{pmatrix}$ by
$$\cos\alpha' = \frac{\begin{pmatrix}2 \\ 3\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}4 \\ 5\end{pmatrix}}{\left|\left|\begin{pmatrix}2 \\ 3\end{pmatrix}\right|\right| \left|\left|\begin{pmatrix}4 \\ 5\end{pmatrix}\right|\right|}.$$
I am looking for a formula that tells me how $\alpha'$ changes when switching the base back to $B$, i.e. a what is the angle $\alpha$ between 
$$\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1\\ 1 & \sqrt{3}\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}2 \\ 3\end{pmatrix} 
\qquad \text{and} \qquad
\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1\\ 1 & \sqrt{3}\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}3 \\ 4\end{pmatrix}$$

**Please note:** I am looking for a **formula** to transform $\alpha'$ to $\alpha$, I want to **avoid recalculation** from scratch.

Comment: I don't think $\alpha$ is a function of $\alpha'$. You could avoid recalculation by coming up with a new formula for the angle using the coordinates in your base instead of the standard one. Does this make sense?

Comment: Have you tried plugging $Mx$ and $My$, where $M$ is a change-of-basis matrix into your formula for angle? That *is* the transformation formula. As @Quimey notes, however, the mapping depends on the two vectors being measured, not solely on the measured angle between them.